Are there really only 4 sets of notes that satisfy this Persichetti requirement?
In 20th Century Harmony, Persichetti classifies major 2nds and minor 7ths as mild dissonances and minor 2nds and major 7ths as sharp dissonances.

He gives the following examples for his classification system:

In a later exercise, he assigns the reader to write a passage using three-note chords that use exactly one consonance, one sharp dissonance, and one mild dissonance.
I am only able to find 4 discrete chords that fit this (ignoring octave displacement for now).  If the top note is a G, the consonance must be a minor third or major sixth away.  This allows the final note to be either a 7th or 9th away, and if it is carefully chosen it forms a mild dissonance with one note and a sharp one with the other.

Is there any other set of notes besides these that would also count?  I deliberately didn't include the tritone because he doesn't classify it as a dissonance; the fourth can be dissonant but isn't described as either mild or sharp.

I haven't gone through Pershetti's book yet. However, the classification seems rather simple compared to CPP harmony. However, when building a harmonic process that isn't essentially dependent on tertial harmony, it could be useful to have some sort of additive version of dissonance. CPP harmony is much less structured. Unisons, octaves, fifths, and fourths* are perfect; thirds and sixths are imperfect; seconds, seventh, augmented, and diminished intervals are dissonance. A fourth is dissonant against the bass but not other wise.

@ttw, re. consonance and dissonance, CCP harmony has only two categories. I'm not familiar with Pershetti, but his categories for consonance and dissonance seem like a modification of major/minor & perfect/altered interval types.

@MichaelCurtis while classic formulations of CPP harmony and counterpoint doesn't necessarily assign names to the mild/sharp distinction, there is indeed some difference in the way they are treated by composers, at least with respect to affect if not in the application of counterpoint rules.  The distinction between soft and open consonances is the same as that between imperfect and perfect consonances, so it could be difficult to isolate Persichetti's purpose (which is perhaps more acoustical) from classic counterpoint (which is significantly if not primarily functional).

@Phoog, yes about mild/sharp dissonance in CPP, but a chain of 2-3 suspensions doesn't seem to make a practical distinction. Also, yes about the soft/open and imperfect/perfect comparison. The interesting thing to me is Persichetti seems to leave mild dissonance M2, m7 and especially neutral A4/d5 as more freely useable than CPP. Not surprising for a 20th century style book.

https://hugoribeiro.com.br/area-restrita/Persichetti-Twentieth_Century_Harmony.pdf

Sorry for the ignorance (I'm not familiar with many technical abbreviations in English), but what is "CPP harmony"?

@musicamante "Common practice period", that is exactly not the subject of Persichetti's book.

TL;DR
By eliminating chords that can be transformed into each other by changing voicing and/or transposition, there are only two unique solutions: C-Db-Eb and C-D-Eb. This is because there is only one collection of intervals that can uniquely satisfy the requirements of the original problem: a chord containing a minor second, a major second, and a minor third.

Discussion
Interval classes
Breaking the interval qualities into interval classes (i.e., 0 = unison, 1 = half step, 2 = whole step, ..., 12 = octave; where 0 = 12 = 24 = ..., 1 = 13 = 25 = ....), we have:

consonances: 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9
mild dissonances: 2, [5?], 10
sharp dissonances: 1, [5?], 11

Exclude 5 (perfect fourth), since it's not clear what type of dissonance Perischetti considers it.
Chords and pitch classes
Since there's no need to consider chords that differ only by transposition, we'll base all of our chords on C. Thus, with pitch classes, we have 0 = C, 1 = C#, 2 = D, ..., 11 = B, and subtraction mod 12 of two pitches will tell us the interval between them. (E.g., C–E = pc 0–pc 4, 4 – 0 = 4 = major third.)
Additional details

Interval qualities are invariant under inversion. That is, inverting a consonant interval results in a consonant interval; inverting a mild dissonance gives a mild dissonance; and inverting a sharp dissonance gives a sharp dissonance. Because of this, we can limit our chords to those that span less than an octave. Any chord spanning more than an octave can be reduced by octave displacement of one or more notes, resulting in either an inverted interval or an equivalent non-compound interval.

Example: Consider the first chord in Perischetti's Ex. 1-14, C-G-E (0, 7, 16). This chord contains the following interval classes [7–mod120=7, 16–mod127=9, 16–mod120=16=4]. If we drop the E one octave, we have (0, 3, 7), resulting in the same interval qualities (i.e., consonances). Alternatively, we could raise the C an octave, resulting in (4, 7, 12), containing interval classes [3, 5, 8]. Either way, the resulting chord contains only consonances.

The two smaller intervals must sum to the largest interval.

Proof: In a 0-based triad, we have pitches (0, x, y), where x < y. (We can require x < y, because in a triad x <> y [otherwise we'd have a dyad], and x > y can be resolved by octave displacement and/or inversion without changing the interval qualities.) This means 0 < x < y.
The chord (0, x, y) contains the intervals [x–0=x, y–x, y–0=y], with y the largest. (y > x is given, and y > y – x is true since y > x > 0. But if we combine the two smallest intervals, we have x+(y–x)=y.
Restating the problem
Create triads containing one of each of the three interval qualities, such that the largest interval is 11 (i.e., spanning less than an octave).
Solution

WLOG, we can eliminate interval 11, because any chord using interval 1 can be inverted to have interval 11.
WLOG, we can eliminate interval 10, because any chord using interval 2 can be inverted to have interval 10.
Therefore, every chord must include intervals 1 and 2, to satisfy the requirement of one interval of each dissonance type.
By the same logic as above, intervals 7, 8, and 9 can be eliminated in favor of 5, 4, and 3, respectively.
This leaves only three possible solutions in intervalic content: [1, 2, 3]; [1, 2, 4], and [1, 2, 5].
Since the two smaller intervals must sum to the larger interval, we have only one possible solution: [1, 2, 3]. In pitch terms, there are only two triads with these intervals: (0, 1, 3) and (0, 2, 3) [(C, Db, Eb) and (C, D, Eb)].

Showing the equivalence of the four original solutions.
The original question offers four solutions: (F#, E, G); (F, E, G); (A, Bb, G); and (Ab, Bb, G).
Reconfigure these to stay within the octave: (E, F#, G); (E, F, G); (G, A, Bb); and (G, Ab, Bb).
Now transpose to C: (C, D, Eb); (C, Db, Eb); (C, D, Eb); and (C, Db, Eb).
We see immediately that there are two pairs of equivalent solutions.

The intervallic content of (C, D, Eb) is [Eb–D=1, D–C=2, Eb–C=3].
The intervallic content of (C, Db, Eb) is [Db–C=1, Eb–Db=2, Eb–C=3].

Therefore, there are only two fundamentally unique solutions. All other solutions are different voicings and/or transpositions of these.
